# Why isn't Perl's File::GlobMapper exporting globmap?

Tags: perl

The following is pretty well copied from the documentation.

```
    use File::GlobMapper qw( globmap );

    for my $pair (globmap '<*.tar.gz>' => '<#1.tgz>' )
     {
     }
```

And it gives

```
    String found where operator expected at globmapper_test1.pl line 4, near "globmap '<*.tar.gz>'"
            (Do you need to predeclare globmap?)
```

(Using ActivePerl 5.10.0 on Windows)

Side questions - if GlobMapper only exports one function, why is it set so you have to export it explicitly?

Comment: Ensure you file a bug report: http://rt.cpan.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in [File::GlobMapper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::GlobMapper).  It sets up the `@EXPORT_OK` variable, but doesn't actually use [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exporter).

But it gets worse.  `globmap` doesn't return a list of arrayrefs (as claimed in the documentation).  It really returns an arrayref of arrayrefs.  So you'd really have to write:

```
use File::GlobMapper; 

for my $pair (@{ File::GlobMapper::globmap('<*.tar.gz>' => '<#1.tgz>') }) { 
  my ($from, $to) = @$pair;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used [File::GlobMapper](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/IO-Compress-2.027/lib/File/GlobMapper.pm), but I dowloaded it from CPAN just now, and
I reproduced your message.  One way around this issue is to use a fully-qualified call
to the `globmap` function.  Give something like this a try:

```
use File::GlobMapper; 

for my $pair (File::GlobMapper::globmap('<*.tar.gz>' => '<#1.tgz>')) 
 { 
 }
```

It appears that the POD does not show the correct way to use the code.
You can submit a bug report on CPAN. It would be best if you included a patch for the
POD.

Looking at the source code for `GlobMapper.pm`, it seems like it does not actually use the Exporter module. This would explain the error message. I don't think the code can export any functions.

Answer (score 1):

For your side question: it doesn't matter how many subroutine names you want to export. It's a good idea to not implicitly import so you don't stomp on anything that the calling file has already done.